# How to bind an image on Page Title in xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

How to bind an image on Page Title in xamarin Forms?

I need to bind a small 24px image icon on the Page Title. App Title Name with logo.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your ContentPage constructor:

```
ToolbarItem ti = new ToolbarItem();
ti.Icon = "logo.png";
this.ToolbarItems.Add(ti);
```